# What is the difference between these two equations? GOOGLE CALC CONFUSION

Tags: math, equation

I'm using google calculator for an equation. The number sixty is a degree.

If I put it in like this, I get:

80 * cos(60) = -76.1930384

But if I put the word 'degrees' I get this:

80 * cos(60degrees) = 40

Which one is the right answer?

Comment: The second answer is what you're looking for. Not really a programming question though, is it?

Comment: How do I represent 60 as an actual degree and not radian in Javascript? 
60 is the degree that I need.

Comment: Is there something like Math.degree to specify a number as a degree in javascript?

Comment: If you have an actual question involving cosine calculation in Javascript, please just ask your actual question. This beating-around-the-bush helps no-one. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specify it to be actual degrees, it will assume it is in PI. Once around the sphere equals 2* PI, which means that your 60 equals 19.09 PI, meaning you got the cosinus for 1.09 PI, or 196 degrees.

Comment: Right, thank you.
In javascript, how would you define my 60 as degrees then?

Comment: @Feeney: No. Correct is: `radian = degrees*Pi/180`

Comment: Is there a Math.degree to specify a number as a degree in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are correct - first one calculates cosinus of 60 radians and the second of 60 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

By default the 60 alone will be considered 60 radians, so that's why you get a different result

Answer (score 0):

80 * cos(60) uses Radians
80 * cos(60degrees) uses Degrees

Since your value (60) is in Degrees, add the keyword 'degrees'

Answer (score 0):

The first calculation is in Radians, the second is (obviously) in Degrees.